# Can I use PostMessage() like this?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, postmessage

I am currently working on an MFC project, which runs several threads and uses `PostMessage()` for the message exchange between the worker thread and the Main UI thread.

I wrote a code like below:

```
UINT ThreadFunc (LPVOID pParam) {
    pointerToMainUI->PostMessage(WM_EXAMPLE, MSG_EXAMPLE_1, 1);    
    pointerToMainUI->PostMessage(WM_EXAMPLE, MSG_EXAMPLE_2, 2); // Question 1
}

void MyDialogExClass::OnBnClickedStart() {
    int intA = 0; // Declared in header as public global

    mThreadA = AfxBeginThread(ThreadFunc , this);
    mThreadB = AfxBeginThread(ThreadFunc , this); // Question 2
}

LRESULT MyDialogExClass::WinProc (WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    
    int iParam = (int)lParam;

    switch (wParam) {
    case MSG_EXAMPLE_1:
        intA = iParam;
        break;

    case MSG_EXAMPLE_2:
        // Do Something
        break;
    }
    
    return LRESULT();
}
```

It is important for my application to do FIFO, which had me wonder if my data and memory is at any risk.

My Question:

1. Is it safe for me to have the thread do two `PostMessage()` calls in a row?
2. Is it safe for me to have two different threads running that will change the value of a variable from the main thread?

Comment: With C++ there is not longer a need to use AfxBeginThread, use [std::thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) instead. (and std::mutex/std::scoped_lock for mutex managment). But yes PostMessage is one of the few really threadsafe winapi functions to call.

Comment: You have 2 questions, SO policy requires one post - one question.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Hi, thanks for the comment. I am using AfxBeginThread is because I am working on a MFC project. I surf from the community saying it is more appropriate to use AfxBeginThread in MFC, although I did not really drill down on the reason.

Comment: @273K Note taken for my future post. Thanks

Comment: @CharonEXE No MFC threads are in most examples because MFC predates C++11 and when MFC was written std::thread did not exist yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In this case, yes. Your posted values are fully contained inside the `lParam` of the messages, so there is no cross-threading issue to post them. If you were posting pointers to values, that would be a different story.
2. In this case, yes. You are not updating the variable directly in your threads, you are delegating the values to the main UI thread, and then it is updating the variable. The messages will be processed one at a time, and the message queue will ensure they are processed in the order that they are posted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the kind answer and also thanks for editing the question to be more understandable too.
I like your answer for pointing out the "if" parts, helps me to know what are the red flag. I am sorry if I asked a foolish question.

Comment: @CharonEXE Certainly not a foolish question, multithreading is not the easiest topic. Lots of little details must be "just right"

Answer (score 0):

Yes what you are doing is ok, except updating using global variables.
Here is an example using std::thread and [lambda functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/lambda-expressions-in-cpp?view=msvc-170)

```
void MyDialogExClass::~MyDialogExClass()
{
    // ensure threads are finished before Dialog is fully destructed.
    // or you might have a race condition.
    m_ThreadA.join();
    m_ThreadB.join();
}

void MyDialogExClass::OnBnClickedStart() 
{
    // Todo : Add some threadsafe logic to avoid click from running while
    // threads are still busy

    // avoid globals!
    // int intA = 0; // Declared in header as public global

    // Do NOT use winapi to start threads
    // it is really cumbersome to pass data to callbacks etc.
    // mThreadA = AfxBeginThread(ThreadFunc, this);
    // mThreadB = AfxBeginThread(ThreadFunc, this); // Question 2

    // use lambda expression to call member functions, or functions using member variables
    // [&] will capture `this` by reference
    // threads will be members of the dialog (you can also use std::async and std::future)
    // std::thread m_ThreadA;
    // std::thread m_ThreadB; 
    mThreadA = std::thread([&] { PostMessage(WM_EXMPLE, MSG_EAMPLE_1, 1); } );
    mThreadB = std::thread([&] { PostMessage(WM_EXMPLE, MSG_EAMPLE_1, 1); });
}

LRESULT MyDialogExClass::WinProc(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    int iParam = (int)lParam;

    switch (wParam) {
    case MSG_EXAMPLE_1:
        // intA = iParam; Do NOT use globals (specialy not in multithreaded env)
        break;

    case MSG_EXAMPLE_2:
        // Do Something
        break;
    }

    return LRESULT{};
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the kiind answer. I picked the other answer as his answer is more relevant to my PostMessage() question, but your answer on the threading part also helps a lot.
Will definitely give it a try. Thanks again.

Comment: It is ok, this was not really a direct answer anyway. More an example :)